# C++: Application crashes with abort() on logging function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex, abort

here is my code which is run on windows:

**Log.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iomanip>

class Log {
public:
    static std::ofstream myfile;
    static std::shared_mutex m_smutex;

    static bool isLogEnabled();
    static void close() {
        Log::myfile.close();
    }
    template< typename... Args >
    static void debug(const char* format, Args... args) {
        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(Log::m_smutex);

        if (isLogEnabled()) {
            if (!Log::myfile.is_open()) {
                Log::myfile.open("C:\\tmp\\log.txt", std::ios_base::app);
            }
            ...
            Log::myfile.close();
        }
        else {
            if (Log::myfile.is_open()) {
                Log::myfile.flush();
                Log::myfile.close();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You can see I've deleted most of the code(...) because I narrowed down the problem.

**Log.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Log.h"

std::ofstream LogLine::myfile;
std::shared_mutex LogLine::m_smutex;
bool LogLine::isLogEnabled() {
    CHAR regeditPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    CHAR variable[] = "DEBUG_LOGS";
    GetEnvironmentVariableA(variable, regeditPath, MAX_PATH);

    return GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND ? false : true;
}
```

The process needs to be run always, that's why I open and close the file everytime I log something. I want to be able to delete logs even when the process is still running. Maybe this is silly because there might be a flag which would allow me to delete the logs while file is open by some process.

Example usage:

```
Log::debug("little test %d", 10);
```

As you can see I use mutex because I want to call `debug` function from different threads. The problem is that after some time I get error code `Abort() has been called` but I can't understand why.

**P.S**
I created this code inside custom Credential Provider to enable debugging, but I'm checking in the internet and it seems like nobody is using logging there. Is it because it's forbidden? Maybe this is reason of the crash?

Comment: Off-topic, but `GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND ? false : true` is a long-winded `GetLastError() != ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Have you tried to catch exceptions? An unhandled exception could be the reason why the program is terminated. Some other possible reasons are here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate

Comment: What makes you so sure that the logger is the ultimate cause of your problems?

Comment: @molbdnilo If I delete everything inside `debug` function except the mutex lock, everything works fine

Comment: That's very weak evidence. "Everything works fine" is the most devious manifestation of undefined behaviour. You need to figure out *why* `abort` was called.

Comment: First, you did not check the file was successfully opened. Instead of keeping it open, did you try to open/close it each time you write into it?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm trying to figure it out, don't you think that's the reason of a question in first place?

Comment: @zdf will try that

Comment: Just because the code crashes here, or if removing this code avoids the crash doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ doesn't work this way. The actual bug can be anywhere in the code that executed prior to this part, which only triggers the crash due to existing memory corruption. This is why Stackoverflow's [help] requires you to show a [mre].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is the minimal reproducible example, I can't paste the whole software code here

Comment: @zdf I tried open/close each time of writing, problem is still occurs. At the moment I wrapped the code inside try/catch block and try to write `e.what()` inside other file. Hope it will succeed

Comment: At the risk of asking about the obvious, are any other messages printed to `stderr` or `stdout` when the abort occurs?  (often a function that calls `abort()` will also print an error message about why, but Windows doesn't always show you `stdout/stderr` output by default so sometimes people don't notice)

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't show anything